# changing description of list of changelist's in perforce

Tags: perforce

I would like to put a common description among a list of change list's , so far i tried this

```
p4 changelist -o >changelist.txt
notepad changelist.txt
```

put the desired description in changelist.txt

`p4 changelist -i` to append the description from changelist.txt

but it will only append the text from chnagelist.txt to a single change list , what i would like to do is append the same description to a list of change list any ideas how to do that .

Answer (score 1):

Put your 'changelist -i' command into a 'for' loop in your favorite scripting language, iterating over all the changelist numbers you wish to update.

Comment: This doesnot seems to be working , what i woould like to do is: 1. there are some submitted change list's 2. i would like to append some common text in start of description field of each of these change lists, can i use p4sql or any other idea ?

Comment: Oh, if they are submitted changelists you have to say 'change -u'. And you have to be the owner of the change, or you have to be an administrator and specify -f. See http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/change.html#1040665